# how to create a model that will be associated with two parent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphic-associations, model-associations, polymorphism

I'm new to rails and still learning the associations and I'm stuck with a model relationship.

I have a model that I want associated with two parent models so that when an instance of that model is created it is automatically associated with the two parent models.  I'm not sure if this is a polymorphic relationship or not.  If it is, can someone show me how to handle the create so that it creates the proper links. I'm not quite getting the polymorphic relationships from the docs.

Currently I'm doing a create with the one model and adding the entry to the other model.  I would like to think there is a way to get this to happen automatically but I'm not sure how to do it.

Current Implementation:

```
entry = @pool.entries.create(new_entry_params)
current_user.entries << entry
current_user.save
```

I want to set it up this way so I can easily show all entries for a specific user from both an instance of the user and an instance of the pool.

Here is what I have so far for the model / database setup:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pools, through: :pool_memberships, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
end

class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, through: :pool_memberships, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pool
end
```

Migration table for entry:

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.references :pool, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.integer :pool_id
      t.integer :user_id, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the "Rails" way of doing this? Or am I way off base.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `current_user.save` as you didn't modify current_user object. :)

This should do the trick:

```
@pool.entries.create(new_entry_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is a much cleaner approach then what I was doing.  I'm still not sure if I'm doing this the "right" way or not but it works!

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord, a polymorphic relationship is one where a model may have one of several possible parents, but it will still only have one parent. It's polymorphic because you don't know which type the parent will be, but you should be able to treat them interchangably. But since you want your model to have two parents at the same time, this isn't what you want.

Your implementation looks fine, though there's no reason to call current_user.save. Test it out, you'll see that in this case the << operator actually triggers the database insert in your join table.